# CMD/BATCH From folders in current location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I believe it should an easy way of doing this, but I could not figure out how.

**Current situation:** 
Customer send zip file to our SFTP folder, by using some easy batch files it copy zip files from SFTP, unzip it and carry on with the rest of the things which has to be done.

**What I need:**

Inside zip file there is a folder(main problem that it could be named randomly). All what I need is a BATCH file which will copy all files from any existing folders in current(job) location.

**Edit:**
Current method is a really bad(but it solid and working), I just simply change the name of the folder in batch file and everything run nice and smooth. Method is working fine, but I would like to automate it completely.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You might find some of the information on the [`FOR` statement at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to be useful...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin there is I lot of methods exist to get the files from folders, but the main problem that everywhere need to specify the folder name (by using variables or any other methods) but need to specify. I'm looking for the method which will extract all files from folders in current job folder.

Comment: Denis, I refer you again to the FOR statement at SS64. If you don't see the relevance, then you need to sit down and really study how the Windows batch language works.

Comment: So, @Denis, If it will help nudge you down the correct road recommended by @Jeff Zeitlin, I'll add the additional bread crumb that you are specifically looking to research `FOR /D` -- the `FOR` command with the `/D` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the directories in the extracted archive directory using `DIR /A:D` which only gets directories. This will process more than one subdirectory if it is found.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "EXTRACTED_DIR=C:\path\to\extracted\archive"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`DIR /A:D /B "%EXTRACTED_DIR%"`) DO (
    SET "THE_DIR=%%~d"
    ECHO Do something with mystery directory "%EXTRACTED_DIR%\!THE_DIR!"
)
```